# Flutter initstate navigator is not working

Tags: flutter

I am using initState and having Navigator issue:

> I/flutter ( 5726): The following assertion was thrown building
>   Builder: I/flutter ( 5726): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called
>   during build.

My Code:

```
@override
void initState() {

super.initState();
print(globals.isLoggedIn);
if(globals.isLoggedIn) {

    print("Already login");

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Dashboard()));

}
```

Comment: Also note that user will be able to return from Dashboard to previous page by pressing back button

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We are getting the error as while `building the Widget` itself we are asking to navigate.

There is a **work around** for this.

```
Future(() {
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Dashboard()));
});
```

**Explaination:**

As Dart is based on *single-threaded event loop*, when we create an **async tasks**, it will put those events in the end of the event queue and continue it's current execution. Please refer below example for more details,

```
void main() {
  print("first");
  Future(() => print("second"));
  print("third");
  Future(() => print("forth"));
}
```

Output will be

```
first
third
second
forth
```

Comment: Great explanation!
Really appreciated
but still, I am getting a warning in the console...
unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you found a solution to this issue?

Answer (score -3):

Embedding the 'MyApp' inside the MaterialApp widget has solved the problem for me.

```
void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(
home:MyApp()
));
}
```