# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter

I am trying to navigate to a page after a specific duration. However, whenever i run the app, i receive an error saying: `At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.`

My code looks like this:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false)
    .then((account) async {
      if (account != null) {
        List<Post> posts = await initTimelinePosts(account.id);
        List<String> followingList = await configureTimelineForNoPost(
          account.id
        );
        currentUser =
          User.fromDocument(await usersRef.document(account.id).get());
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Home(
              posts: posts,
              followingList: followingList,
              savedState: widget.savedState
            )
          )
        );
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: RouteSettings(name: Auth.route),
            builder: (context) => Auth(savedState: widget.savedState)
          )
        );
      }
    }).catchError((_) async {
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String userId = prefs.getString('userId');
      if (userId != null && userId.isNotEmpty) {
        DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(userId).get();
        currentUser = User.fromDocument(doc);
        List<Post> posts = await initTimelinePosts(userId);
        List<String> followingList = await configureTimelineForNoPost(userId);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Home(
              posts: posts,
              followingList: followingList,
              savedState: widget.savedState,
            )
          )
        );
      } else {
        _timer = new Timer(
          Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
          () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement( // the error message points to this line
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                settings: RouteSettings(name: Auth.route),
                builder: (context) => Auth(savedState: widget.savedState)
              )
            );
          }
        );
      }
    });
}
```

I expect the app to run without errors but it doesn't. How do I solve this?

Note: I seriously don't know what to write anymore and SO keeps complaining that i need to add some more details. I believe i've provided enough explanation with the description, the title, and the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to navigate to a new page and replace this page in your initState(). Because the widget tree is not built when you run initState() method, it might cause an error.

Have a look at [this answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19330#issuecomment-405426564) for detailed explanation and [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19462) for a similar issue.

Comment: okay, thanks, i solved the issue by checking if the context is not null

Comment: I ran the app and the error came back again, although, it went away for the first time, when i added the if check so i don't know why. Also, i noticed that code execution doesn't reach that line because i tried printing there and it doesn't work so i wonder why it is trying to navigate when it is supposed not to

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51965749/12828249). It might help